# How to connect to device with BlueZ in C?

Tags: linux, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez

Is there a sample code for connecting to ble device using bluez with C code? http://www.bluez.org/release-of-bluez-5-64/ I reviewed the software here, but it was very comprehensive and difficult to understand. Is there a simpler software?

Comment: The API docs can be found at https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc. You should get familiar with d-bus first and learn that technology before you start using this api.

Comment: There are several libraries that make using Bluez in C easier. E.g. Gattlib and Bluez_inc. Disclaimer, I am the author of Bluez_inc....

Comment: Hello, Martijn van Welie,

How can I run the code on your Github page. I'm new to Linux. When I try to compile your codes, I get library errors like gio.h. When I did some research I saw that I need to edit the makefile but I don't know how to fix it? Can you help me ? Thank you...

Comment: @ilkerekmen, I added more build instructions to the README. Make sure you have the GLib dependency installed...

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is to get familiar with the BlueZ command line tools (especially **bluetoothctl**), and then read the source code for this tool to understand how BLE operations (including BLE) are implemented. You can find info on how to use **bluetoothctl** here:-

- [How to manage Bluetooth devices on Linux using bluetoothctl](https://www.makeuseof.com/manage-bluetooth-linux-with-bluetoothctl/)
- [BLE on Linux with bluetoothctl](https://budimir.cc/2020/02/27/ble-on-linux-with-bluetoothctl/)
- [Accessing GATT services](https://ubuntu.com/core/docs/bluez/reference/accessing-gatt-services)

You can then download the source code (available [here](https://github.com/bluez/bluez)), and view the code for connection using bluetoothctl (found [here](https://github.com/bluez/bluez/blob/master/client/main.c#L2098)).

Alternatively, you can search for the BlueZ C function for connecting to Bluetooth devices (ConnectDevice), and download simple examples from the web. This is something I found using a quick search:-

- [Connect Bluetooth device without scanning](https://gist.github.com/parthitce/eb6b751df3235f7247babc4c9aba41d8)